# Mathematical expressions in Matplotlib 1.3.1

Tags: python, syntax, matplotlib

I am trying to write mathematical expressions in `matplotlib.pyplot` version 1.3.1

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> print matplotlib.__version__
    1.3.1
```

A snippet of the code that does not work is

```
plt.scatter(np.log10(r1),np.log10(xi1),c='red',label='$\xi$(r) M$_{200}$>13.4')
plt.plot(np.log10(r1),np.log10(curve_y_1),'--',label='fit M200>13.4')

plt.text(0.5,-1.6,'0.0<z<1.0',fontsize=15,color='c')
plt.text(0.5,-1.8,'r$_0$ = %g' % p1_1,fontsize=13,color='r')
plt.text(0.5,-2.0,'$\gamma$ = %g' % p1_2,fontsize=13,color='r')
```

The entire traceback of the error is:

```
In [55]: %run correlation_fit_compare.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    202             else:
    203                 filename = fname
--> 204             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

The [Matplotib website](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) mentions that anything enclosed within a `$` and `\` should give me the required expression. One of their examples is $\alpha$ which gives them the "math" alpha.

Can anyone tell me how to write  \xi in my label?

**EDIT: HAVE POSTED THE ENTIRE plt CODE and the ENTIRE TRACEBACK**

Comment: Can you post your full traceback as well please? Also I assume you plotting the same line (plt.scatter) twice is an editing mistake?

Comment: Ok. Can you please close your ipython console and restart it? And then ensure that you're running the correct python file and that you have placed `r` before ALL strings that contain some TeX code (I see in your code that you've placed it in one (the middle `plt.text`) but not in others)? Just worried that it might be cached or some such and you're still running the old code.

Comment: the middle r in plt.text is actually r_0. As I mentioned, I have also tried plotting it with removing my plt.text and plt.plot lines.. But still it says ValueError

Comment: Well I have used your exact plotting syntax with some fake data **with the filled in raw strings** and it works fine for me. As such I am unable to help you further because I am simply unable to reproduce your problem if I use the solution that both myself and Davidmh have given you.

Comment: I shall keep fiddling with it, thanks

Answer (score 5):

When using mathematical text with matplotlib you must use a raw string as opposed to a standard string. In a standard string `\` is used as an escape character, such as `\n` representing a new line.

To convert your strings to raw-strings is simple, you'll notice that the matplotlib examples place an `r` before the start of the string such as `r'$\alpha$'`.

In your case you would change it to:

```
plt.scatter(np.log10(r1),np.log10(xi1),c='red',label=r'$\xi$(r) M$_{200}$>13.4')
```

Comment: I have tried your edit, it still says ValueError: invalid \x escape

Comment: Yes I have one more plot function, which has label = 'fit', i.e a normal string

Comment: I have also tried removing all the lines and just plotting plt.scatter. But still I get the Value error

Answer (score 2):

In Python, some backslash combinations have special meanings. You can avoid that using raw strings. Also, you should be using only one pair of `$`, as it is only one expression:

```
r'$\xi(r)\ M_{200}>13.4$'
```

This means "take everything inside the string literally". It is a good idea to always use raw strings involving LaTeX expressions.

Note that the output is a normal string, the `r` is just telling the parser not to use escape characters.

Note also than in LaTeX, space is indicated by a `\` (slash-space).

**Edit**

Now you have posted your expressions, I can tell you what is wrong with each one:

- `'$\xi$(r) M$_{200}$>13.4'`: several `$`, where you should have only one. See above.
- `'fit M200>13.4'`: No LaTeX here, but it would be `r'$\mathrm{fit}\ M200>13.4$'`
- `'r$_0$ = %g' % p1_1`: the `r` should be outside, and the `$` enclosing the full expression. `r'$r_0 = %g$' % p1_1`
- `'$\gamma$ = %g' % p1_2`: same as above, use only one pair of `$` enclosing the full expression: `r'$\gamma = %g$' % p1_2`

***NOTE:*** technically, you *can* mix LaTeX and no LaTeX expressions, but it is error prone, as you can miss a delimiter, and looks ugly.

Comment: @Srivatsan got it, it is because you are using several dollar signs. See the edited command

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the character \ so it's not interpreted as the escape character \x, like this:

```
plt.scatter(np.log10(r1),np.log10(xi1),c='red',label='$\\xi$(r) M$_{200}$>13.4')
```

Also the parameter label of a plot doesn't actually show anything unless you add a legend to your plot, so after that you will have to either call:

```
plt.legend()
```

Or create an xlabel or ylabel instead of labeling the plot:

```
plt.xlabel(label='$\\xi$(r) M$_{200}$>13.4')
plt.ylabel(label='$\\xi$(r) M$_{200}$>13.4')
```